# Appending value to variable

Tags: php

Hoping someone can steer me in the right direction. I have a form with an input field and a button. When the input field is populated and the button clicked the value of the field displays in the variable $capture_numbers.

Id like to be able to add to that value i.e person enters 1, $capture_numbers displays 1, person enters 2, $capture_numbers now displays 1, 2, person enters 3, $capture_numbers now displays 1, 2, 3 and so on. I'm thinking along the lines of storing the previous value and appending to it but cant figure out how it's done. Below is my script.

```
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
        <fieldset>
           <input type="text" name="mynumbers[]">
           <button>add another numbers</button>
           <input type="submit" value="Submit" title="submit">
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <?php
         if(isset($_POST['mynumbers']) && is_array($_POST["mynumbers"])) {
            $capture_numbers = ' ';
            foreach($_POST["mynumbers"] as $key => $value) {
                $capture_numbers .= $value .", ";
            }
            echo $capture_numbers;
         }
    ?>
```

Comment: what's with the approved edit? "Thanks in advance" is noise which I removed in a previous edit. Let's not make this an edit war, ok? thanks. You can thank whoever gives you a solution by accepting it.

Comment: you need sessions for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need some persistent storage to store previous submissions. Valid options are a database, local storage, cookies, session etc.

In this example, I used session. When the form is submitted, check the session for previous entries and then append the new one to the list. I've added comments in the code.

**Edit**: You don't need to add the text field as an array. Ie. name="mynumbers[]". That is usually used for when you have multiple inputs with the same name and want to read them as an array.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="number">
        <button>add another numbers</button>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" title="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>

<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

// Check if form is submitted
if (!empty($_POST)) {

    // Create a variable to store all numbers
    $allNumbers = [];

    // Does the session contain anything
    if (isset($_SESSION['previous'])) {
        // Grab it from the session as an array and store it
        $allNumbers = explode(',', $_SESSION['previous']);
    }

    // Append the new number to the list
    $allNumbers[] = $_POST['number'];

    // Convert it to a comma separated string
    $capture_numbers = implode(',', $allNumbers);

    // Store the entire list in the session
    $_SESSION['previous'] = $capture_numbers;

    // Output the result
    echo $capture_numbers;
}
```